# MPI_Test not progressing MPI_Isend/MPI_Irecv requests

Tags: c++, asynchronous, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing

I am running a CFD simulation with a 200,000-vertex mesh. I've decomposed the mesh into 2 load-balanced sub-domains to test my parallel implementation. In the specific function that I am time-profiling, each sub-domain has to send a 3D gradient vector of `MPI_DOUBLE`s for each of the ~2000 vertices that lie on the parallel communication boundary. The vertex list is sorted such that all vertices involved in parallel communication lie at the start of the list (ivertParaCommStart is the parallel vertex in the list with the largest index). The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
MPI_Request sendRequ; // Local variable in each thread
MPI_Request recvRequ; // Local variable in each thread
for(ivert, mvert)
{
  // Perform costly calculations for each vertex.....

  if(ivert == ivertCommStart)
  {
    // Load data from ALL parallel vertices and communicate with other thread.
    MPI_Isend(..., ..., MPI_DOUBLE, (ithread == 0 ? 1 : 0), ..., ..., &sendRequ);
    MPI_Irecv(..., ..., MPI_DOUBLE, (ithread == 0 ? 1 : 0), ..., ..., &recvRequ);
  }
  else if(ivert > ivertCommStart)
  {
    MPI_Test(&sendRequ, ..., ...);
    MPI_Test(&recvRequ, ..., ...);
  }
}

bool isallComm = false;
while(!isallComm)
{
  isallComm = true;
  isallComm = isallComm ? MPI_Test(&sendRequ, ...) : false;
  isallComm = isallComm ? MPI_Test(&recvRequ, ...) : false;
}
```

Considering that the total number of parallel communication vertices is ~4000 in each sub-domain (~4% of the total number of vertices) and considering the cost of the computations performed for each vertex, I would have expected that the data transfer would be completely masked by the computations performed over the remaining non-parallel vertices. However, this is not the case. Note that after the `MPI_Wait` calls do eventually return, I have confirmed that the data exchanged is as I would expect (parallel simulations produce equivalent results to a serial simulation). However, the cost of the `MPI_Wait()` calls yields very poor scaling of my code. Can anyone advise me on why `MPI_Test()` is not progressing my send and receive requests?

**EDIT**: Apologies for any confusion caused - I should clarify that I communicate the data for *all* parallel vertices in one go.

**EDIT 2**: I have found that the `MPI_Test` calls do not allow me to overlap the communication and computation. They have a significant overhead. Effectively, the total time for the `for` loop + `MPI_Wait` calls is the same as if I wait till the end of the `for` loop and then communicate the parallel data using blocking send/recv calls (the code below takes the same amount of time to run as the code above). So I am seeing no benefit of the non-blocking communication. I am relatively new to `MPI`. I would appreciate any advice on what could be going on here.

```
for(ivert, mvert)
{
  // Perform costly calculations for each vertex.....
}

// Load data from ALL parallel vertices and communicate with other thread.
MPI_Request sendRequ; 
MPI_Request recvRequ;
MPI_Isend(..., ..., MPI_DOUBLE, (ithread == 0 ? 1 : 0), ..., ..., &sendRequ);
MPI_Irecv(..., ..., MPI_DOUBLE, (ithread == 0 ? 1 : 0), ..., ..., &recvRequ);
bool isallComm = false;
while(!isallComm)
{
  isallComm = true;
  isallComm = isallComm ? MPI_Test(&sendRequ, ...) : false;
  isallComm = isallComm ? MPI_Test(&recvRequ, ...) : false;
}
```

Comment: MPI_Test guarantees to eventually progress operation, but it is MPI implementation-dependent how long you can wait for this to happen. I would suggest replacing MPI_Wait by MPI_Test with loop as well to make sure that MPI_Test does what you expect. If this works, then you can try to count the number of calls to MPI_Test inside the for loop and outside to see how far you are from completion, maybe your workload is not large enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response! In fact, in my implementation, the last two lines are replaced with `MPI_Test()` calls in a while loop which exits if both requests are complete (I used `MPI_Wait` here because I thought it's equivalent to `MPI_Test` in a while loop?). The while loop iterates anywhere between ~3000 and ~15000 iterations till completion. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "maybe your workload is not large enough?".

Comment: I mean that it is possible that the number of calls to MPI_Test inside the for loop and time that the code spends there is too small for MPI implementation to actually make any progress. This also could be an issue from MPI side, you can try other MPI implementations to see if they work as you expect.

Comment: you do not `MPI_Test()` the requests created by `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irecv()`. Also, `MPI_Wait()` is outside the `for` loop, so you might be missing some requests.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The reason I put `MPI_Wait` outside the for loop is because I don't want it to be blocking until I've finished all computations. But perhaps I am misunderstanding you. What do you mean by "...might be missing some requests?".

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I should probably clarify in my post that I send all parallel data at once.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, if one `for` loop issues exactly two non blocking requests, then you are fine.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet My problem is that the `MPI_Test` calls do not allow me to overlap the communication and computation. They actually have a significant overhead. Effectively, the total time for the `for` loop + `MPI_Wait` calls is the same as if I wait till the end of the `for` loop and then communicate the parallel data using blocking send/recv calls. So I am seeing no benefit of the non-blocking communication. Any advice?

Comment: If the MPI implementation does not feature a progress thread, then `MPI_Test()` progresses the communications (instead of computing) so there is a risk to end up with zero overlap.

Comment: Okay I see, is there an `MPI` call for spawning a progress thread? Or is this something I need to handle at compile-time?

Comment: The most portable thing to do is have periodic calls to `MPI_Test` inside `// Perform costly calculations for each vertex.....`. Or spawn a separate application thread and call `MPI_Test()` in a loop there. There are no MPI calls to start asynchronous progression - it is either there and always working or not there at all. There may be configuration parameters, both compile- or run-time ones, that enable async progression for your particular MPI implementation.

Comment: Also, since you have two requests, you can put them in an array and use `MPI_Testall`. It signals the flag only once all requests have completed.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you for this insight. When you say "...it is either there and always working or not there at all", on what factors does the existence of asynchronous progression depend?

Comment: Citing myself: _"There may be configuration parameters, both compile- or run-time ones, that enable async progression for your particular MPI implementation."_ Note that enabling asynchronous progression usually results in increased communication latency. Also, for networks that require polling, the progress thread may eat a lot of CPU resources, which could also be the case with networks that do not necessarily require polling but where busy polling reduces the latency.